# How to prove that if Eternal Vertex Cover is Polynomial it's possible to detect its vertices and edges

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time, vertex-cover

EVG is defined as EVC = { <G,m,k>| G is an undirected graph and there is as et of m edges in G that are covered by at most k nodes}

If EVG was decidable in polynomial time how could we find the list of m vertices and k nodes that satisfy it in polynomial time?

Here's the best solution I found:
Run EVC repeatedly with k=k-1 until it's not longer accepted. That would be our min boundary for  (call it k')
Same thing with increasingly higher m until we find for k' the max number of m (call it m')

Then add an external node and connect it each time with a different node in G and run EVC.
If it's rejected it means that the node that we connected to is part of the EVG otherwise it isn't.
This was we can detect a minimum k' nodes and maximum m' edges and output them.

Problem is that if there are more than 1 EVG the might fail.

Answer (score 1):

##### The simple idea

Keep removing nodes from $G$, maintaining $\langle G, m, k\rangle\in \text{EVC}$ without ever changing $m$ and $k$.

##### A simple algorithm

Suppose $\langle G=(V,E), m, k\rangle\in\text{EVC}$.

1. Let $D$ be an algorithm (or an oracle) that decides $\text{EVC}$ in polynomial time.
2. While $|V|\gt |k|$:

   - for each node $v$ in $V$:

     1. check whether $\langle G\text{ without }v, m, k\rangle\in \text{EVC}$ using $D$.
     2. If yes, remove $v$ from $G$, updating $V$ and $E$ accordingly and then breaking this "for each" loop.
3. Now $|V|\le k$. Let $U$ be any set of $m$ edges in $E$. Return $(U,V)$.

---

Note that it is always true that $\langle G, m, k\rangle\in \text{EVC}$
during the algorithm. Whenever the algorithm runs the "for each" loop, it will remove a node from $G$ since $\langle G, m, k\rangle\in \text{EVC}$ and $|V|\gt k$ before the loop. So the "while" loop will executes the "for each" loop at most $n-k$ times, where $n$ is the number of nodes in $V$ initially.

Each execution of the "for each" loop calls $D$ at most $n$ times since $|V|$ can only becomes smaller. Since $D$ runs in polynomial time and $G$ can only become smaller, the whole algorithm runs in polynomial time as well.